# htaccess redirect using different parameter name and(or) value

Tags: php, regex, .htaccess

I have an page with multiple parameters. Is it possible to change the url's like below using htaccess or using php.

```
http://example.com/result.php?year=2012
Change To
http://example.com/year-2012

http://example.com/result.php?category=naturals
Change To
http://example.com/category-naturals

http://example.com/result.php?year=2012&category=naturals
Change To
http://example.com/year-2012/category-naturals
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do it using .htaccess. Try something like this:

```
RewriteRule ^year-(.*)  result.php?year=$1 [PT]
RewriteRule ^category-(.*)  result.php?category=$1 [PT]
RewriteRule ^year-(.*)/category-(.*)  result.php?year=$1&category=$2 [PT]
```

Comment: solution for single parameter is working perfect. But the solution for 2 parameters is not working perfect. It's takes as single parameter and I get following when I print request values.
Array
(
    [year] => 2012/category-2013
)
I must need to study regular expression

Answer (score 0):

```
(http:\/\/.*\/).*?\?(?:(\w+)=(\w+)&?)*
```

Try this.Replace by `$1$2-$3`.See demo.

http://regex101.com/r/yA1jY6/2

Answer (score 0):

You can have these rules in your root .htaccess:

```
RewriteRule ^year-([^/]+)/?$                  result.php?year=$1             [NC,L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^category-([^/]+)/?$              result.php?category=$1         [NC,L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^year-([^/]+)/category-([^/]+)/?$ result.php?year=$1&category=$2 [NC,L,QSA]
```